# Unable to find CsvReader no matter what I try

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.lang.class

So I am trying to make the following code work "https://github.com/jintrone/TEVA", only problem is that I am a Java newbie. At first I got compilation error "it.uniroma1.dis.wsngroup.gexf4j.core does not exist" which I solved by downloading and adding gexf4j jar into the ./lib/ folder. Now the compilation is successful but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/csvreader/CsvReader
```

The file I get this from does the following `import com.csvreader.*;` I downloaded `opencsv-2.4.jar` and `opencsv-3.7.jar` and put them in lib but to no avail (also, lib already contains `javacsv.jar`). I tried to modify the code to `import opencsv.csvreader`, `import au.com.csvreader'...` only to get `error: package ... does not exist`.

Anyone have an idea? these lang issues are tough on a newbie.

Thank you all

Comment: The class you are seeking should be in **javacsv.jar** for **lib** folder. Are you sure this file is there? How did you download the sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below a working step by step howto

1. get the source repository, either by `git clone https://github.com/jintrone/TEvA.git` or downloading the ZIP file `https://github.com/jintrone/TEvA/archive/master.zip`
2. download a missing library from `http://central.maven.org/maven2/it/uniroma1/dis/wsngroup/gexf4j/gexf4j/1.0.0/gexf4j-1.0.0.jar` and store it in the `lib/` directory
3. build the project `ant`

The build will finish with some warnings (had no look after that).

Then you can start the example as (for more information check the   README.md of the project)

```
cd deploy/
java -cp TEvA.jar edu.mit.cci.teva.example.RunSampleCsv ...
```

**edit** You might need to amend the file `resources/cfinderbatch.properties` (before the build with `ant`) and change the path to the `cfinder` application.

```
cfinderapplication=/usr/local/bin/cfinder
```

Change the path to your binary `CFinder_commandline` (e.g. `cfinderapplication=/your/path/CFinder_commandline`). Following the [manual](http://hal.elte.hu/cfinder/wiki/?n=Main.Manual#toc13) it should be in the top directory where you have extracted the `CFinder*.zip` archive. Most probably you need to set the executable flag `chmod +x CFinder_commandline`.

If all this doesn't solve your problem you might try to contact the [CFinder people](http://cfinder.org/wiki/?n=Main.Support).

Comment: Finally getting somewhere! This solves the issues I had before. But now when executing the command I get:

`Exception in thread "main" edu.mit.cci.teva.engine.CommunityFinderException: Error processing network files`

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/cfinder": error=2, No such file or directory`

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`

I think the program does find the "cfinder". But I still have permission problem somewhere? any ideas?

Comment: @user44874 This exception doesn't look like a permission problem `No such file or directory`. Have you checked that the file exist and is executable? e.g. `ls -l /usr/local/bin/cfinder`.

Comment: No, I do not. I do find a cfinder directory in the `teva` code: `/TEvA-master/src/edu/mit/cci/teva/cpm/cfinder` I imported the three files in this dir to the RunSampleCsv but nothing changed.
How do I install cfinder on ubuntu 14.04? I downloaded `CFinder-2.0.6--1448` but there is no way to install it, instead there is a start.sh which opens a widget when run.

Comment: @user44874 Have a look if my updated answer could solve this problem.